# Big Sur can't see pre-Big Sur Time Machine saves

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

My Big Sur upgrade had severe problems, to the point where I had to reformat the disk and install as a fresh system. Once I got the "fresh" install done, yesterday, I started restoring individual files and directories via Time Machine.

Today, I can't access any Time Machine backups before 2200 local, last night, which is well after the reinstall and restore.

I know the data is on the Time Machine disk, because I was using it. How do I troubleshoot this, and how can I continue to restore files?

Comment: Can you attach relevant TM logs?

Comment: If open finder, select your TM drive and go into the backups folder, can you see the backups folder of previous backups? You should always be able to manually select your files from there and copy them back.